# What is the proper way to replace a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a MySQL database `mydb` and a database in a test environment `mytestdb` which mirrors `mydb`. I need a way of "pushing changes" from the test database to the live one. So the procedure in pseudo-code would be like

```
for each table T in mydb
   delete all from T
   T' = corresponding table in mytestdb
   for each row R in T' 
       insert R in T
```

or should I be doing that procedure differntly? Any potential problems with this setup?

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:

```
DROP TABLE x;
Create and Load its replacement.
```

Plan B (more suited for reloading a table in a *live* situation):

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
LOAD TABLE new ...                      -- slowest step
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;  -- atomic and 'instantaneous'
DROP TABLE old;
```